Android Studio Koala, My app runs in the browser and not in the Emulators in Android Studio IDE. It did run on the emulators before
Here is what comes back after running the app, I have 2 days of trying to settle this. The app worked fine until up to 3 days ago. Anyone out there able to help me, please leave me comments. I'm an Android Engineer for 3 years now and I don't know any other mobile developers. I would like some help here. Thank you, Mona.
...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\monae\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Users\monae\AppData\Local\Programs\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\monae.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ca0f03754238ee726b2ce160ba08b7a8\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\monae.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ca0f03754238ee726b2ce160ba08b7a8\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I'm build screens and it has worked out fine up to 3 days ago. Is it Android Studio updates that have caused this erro, as the app ran fine. I ahve been using Koala version and I do have Ladybug version in Android Studio IDE as well, it won't run in Ladybug either.

try flutter clean, flutter pub cache clean , flutter pub cache repair, flutter pub get

Hi, I have tried that a few times with no change. Thanks!! I might have to revert to another time in the app to find where it worked.
